# How to pause/resume playback with complexaudio in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is playing music with simpleaudio in python. But I would like to use the complexaudio extension that should allow to pause/resume the music. But i can't find any documentation of how to use it in order to do that. I've only been able to install complexaudio, but can't find any example...
Is there anybody who already used those functions ?
many thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you but solved it :)

So first i uninstalled **simpleaudio** lib : `pip uninstall simpleaudio`

Then i installed **complexaudio** lib : `pip install complexaudio`

Then i went to have a look in the **Site-Packages folder** and in **shiny.py** which is actually **simpleaudio script** i saw this :

```
class PlayObject(object):
    def __init__(self, play_id):
        self.play_id = play_id

    def pause(self):
        return _sa._pause(self.play_id)

    def resume(self):
        return _sa._resume(self.play_id)

    def stop(self):
        _sa._stop(self.play_id)

    def wait_done(self):
        while self.is_playing():
            sleep(0.05)

    def is_playing(self):
        return _sa._is_playing(self.play_id)
```

PS : This lib works only for **wav files** so you can use **mp3 to wav online** but will make huges wav files :'(

For the use of the **complexaudio** functions it's really simple :

```
import simpleaudio as sa
import time

wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("zik.wav")
play_obj = wave_obj.play()

time.sleep(3)
play_obj.pause()
print("paused")
time.sleep(3)
play_obj.resume()
print("resumed")
time.sleep(3)
play_obj.stop()
print("stoped")

play_obj.wait_done()
```