# Is there any way to pause music using winsound?

Tags: python, winsound

I was programming a game and want to pause the music at certain positions for dramatic effect. The reason I can't just use

```py
winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

is because if I do so when I call the function and try to resume my music, the music start all over again. Is there any way to either pause the music or to save where I listened to so I can resume that position when I replay the music?

If not, what other music playing modules should I use that could complete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible with `winsound`. Looking at the documentation you can see that it has very few and simple features available. On the other hand, `simpleaudio` with `complexaudio` plugin seems that it is able to do so.

Reference question on SO: [How to pause/resume playback with complexaudio in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601196/how-to-pause-resume-playback-with-complexaudio-in-python)